# run script at reboot

Tags: scripts

I would like to run this script everytime computer starts up. I'm using crontab/gnome schduler:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    fileName=$(inotifywait -e create /home/posto-11v/Documents/Processo | sed -r 's/^.*CREATE(,ISDIR)*\s+(.*)$/\2/g')
    zenity --warning --text="$fileName"
done
```

this is the crontab -e file:

```bsh
@reboot sh /home/posto-11v/Documents/personaproject/Programa/scripts/recebe_processo # JOB_ID_9
```

I've changed script permissions using chmod +x.

I'm not able to run it automatically, only by hand. what i'm doing wrong? Can the script start whithout starting the terminal?

thks in advance!

Comment: You should have mentioned it requires a GUI.  If it requires a GUI, then you can't use crontab or rc.local to run it.  Read @Gilles answer for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script can't be executed at reboot: it needs a graphical environment. You need to log in first, to start a graphical environment where you can run zenity. Run the script from your session startup. See [Adding programs to session startup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddingProgramToSessionStartup) in the Ubuntu community documentation.

Comment: thank you, it's working...so simple, sometimes we think that ubuntu, must be more complicated than MSW...that's stupid! ;)